# Juntar dois Jsons em um único objeto

Tags: javascript, parse

**Tenho o seguinte json:**

```
{  
   "razao_social":"INTELIDER",
   "nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA",
   "rg_insc_estadual":"123456"
}
```

**E outro json:**

```
{  
   "usuario":{  
      "login":"gleyson",
      "senha":"987654"
   }
}
```

Preciso que ele fique dessa maneira:

```
{  
       "usuario":{  
          "login":"gleyson",
          "senha":"987654"
       },
       "razao_social":"INTELIDER",
       "nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA",
       "rg_insc_estadual":"123456"
}
```

Tentei fazer usando **parse** porém não consegui exito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar o `Object.assign`

```js
var obj1 = {
  "razao_social":"INTELIDER",
  "nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA",
  "rg_insc_estadual":"123456" 
};
var obj2 = { 
  "usuario":{
    "login":"gleyson",
    "senha":"987654"
  }
};

var obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj);
```

antes de utilizar o recurso acima, veja se todos os browsers à que você dá suporte tem suporte à este método, você pode conferir isto em: [`Mozilla MDN - Object.assign - Browser compatibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility)

Se necessário, adicione o seguinte **Polyfill**:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    var to = Object(target);

    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var nextSource = arguments[index];

      if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
        for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
          // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return to;
  };
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um novo objeto que contenha as propriedades de seus JSON's, não importa quantos sejam, e então passar para JSON novamente.

Por exemplo:

```
var json1 = { "razao_social":"INTELIDER", "nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA", "rg_insc_estadual":"123456" };
var json2 = { "login":"gleyson","senha":"987654" };
var json3 = { "foo": "bar"};
var json4 = { "etc": "etc. acho que já deu pra entender" };
var json5 = { "palmeiras": { "quantidadeMundiais": "0" } };

var jsonRangers = [json1, json2, json3, json4, json5];

var jsonZord = {};
for (var i = 0; i < jsonRangers.length; i++) {
    for (var propriedade in jsonRangers[i]) {
        jsonZord[propriedade] = jsonRangers[i][propriedade];
    }
}

JSON.stringify(jsonZord); // Só pra mostrar o resultado no console.
```

Comment: +1 `jsonRangers` e `jsonZord`

Comment: @Renan , obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 2):

É só aproveitar a dinamicidade do JavaScript e atribuir o segundo objeto como propriedade `usuario` do primeiro objeto.

```js
var obj1 = { "razao_social":"INTELIDER","nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA","rg_insc_estadual":"123456" };
var obj2 = { "usuario":{"login":"gleyson","senha":"987654"} };

obj1.usuario = obj2.usuario;

console.log(obj1);
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode atribuir:

```js
var json1 = { "razao_social":"INTELIDER","nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA","rg_insc_estadual":"123456"}


var json2 = { "usuario":{"login":"gleyson","senha":"987654"} }

json1.usuario = json2.usuario;
console.log(json1)
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Com jQuery, basta utilizar o [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). Ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```js
$(function() {
  foo = {
    "razao_social": "INTELIDER",
    "nome_fantasia": "INTELIDER LTDA",
    "rg_insc_estadual": "123456"
  };

  bar = {
    "usuario": {
      "login": "gleyson",
      "senha": "987654"
    }
  };

  // Comando que faz a mesclagem
  fooBar = $.extend(foo, bar);

  console.log(fooBar);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Um item importante a levar em consideração é, com Object.assign sub itens não são mesclados, utilizando $.extend do jQuery sim.

Veja este exemplo para entender melhor:

```js
$(function() {
  obj1 = {
    nome: 'teste 1',
    subItem: {
      conta: 100
    }
  };

  obj2 = {
    nome2: 'teste 2',
    subItem: {
      conta2: 200
    }
  };

  recursivo = $.extend(true, {}, obj1, obj2);
  naoRecursivo = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

  // diff
  console.log(recursivo); // possui conta e conta2
  console.log(naoRecursivo); // nao possui conta
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```